Is this sentence grammatically correct: "Explore the world through here, becoming lifelong learners."
The following sentence is written on a sign at the entrance of a school:

Explore the world through here, becoming lifelong learners.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
The phrase "through here" sounds awkward to me. Also, it seems that "becoming" modifies "explore"; I'm not sure if a gerund can be used to modify a command like that.

A slogan or motto doesn't have to be a perfect sentence. Often they're just strings of nouns or adjectives.

@StuartF Fair enough. But I still want to know if it is grammatically correct.

"Through here" = "by means of our institution". An imperative has an implied subject "you", so readers of the sign are invited to become lifelong learners.

@KateBunting I know what it means, I'm just wondering if it is grammatically correct.

And I was trying to explain how the sentence works (acknowledging Stuart's point that a slogan doesn't have to be a formal sentence). The subject of becoming is "you" (plural).

@KateBunting So would you say "yes" or "no"?

That question is unanswerable, for the reason already given.

@KateBunting If the sentence appeared in a formal setting, not a slogan, would it be considered grammatically correct?

I don't know about the 'grammar' but, being a slogan, it would not be appropriate to use it in a formal context.

We wouldn't normally include preposition through before here, just as we wouldn't include at in I live [at] here, or to in I'm going [to] there. Something to do with here, there being "adverbs of location", I guess, since we do include the prepositions in I live at this place and I'm going to that place. And the continuous participle (not gerund) becoming is at the very least stylistically awkward in the cited context, where we'd expect the parallelism of ...and become lifelong learners.

Note, something can be grammatically valid and still be "awkward" or unclear. Language is a set of tools, and grammar is how you use them. I might be using a screwdriver correctly, but if my goal is to make a hole in a piece of wood, a drill would be a better choice.

Whatever it means, it can’t possibly be native English.

Be a lifelong learner here, not actually abroad, forever. That could be less tempting, as an ad.

What the sign means is:

When people go through here [the door], they will explore the world and become lifelong learners.

or

Enter through here to explore the world and become a lifelong learners.

Signage is often terse, not meant to be parsed as full, grammatical sentences ("no smoking" and "authorized entry only" are not grammatical, either).
That said, the two clauses don't seem to have proper parallel structure. The first is an imperative, using a bare infinitive, while the second clause uses a present participle. Participle phrases are usually used in dependent clauses to qualify the verb of the main clause, e.g.

Clean the dishes, scrubbing the pots thoroughly.

But that's not how "becoming lifelong learners" is intended here. It's meant as another result of going to the school. It might be better worded as

Explore the world through here, and become lifelong learners.

Using "through here" also seems like synecdoche. Going through the door is a metaphor for enrolling in the school.

I'd argue that "sweep the floor" doesn't need to be understood "you can sweep the floor," and that marketing imperatives can still be understood as imperatives, just ones we (usually) have the option to decline. Meanwhile, can it really be a violation of parallelism to say "Sweep the floor, paying special attention to the corners?" (Or for that matter, "O'er the fields we go, laughing all the way?") I realize you're not supporting such a position yourself, but I have a hard time imagining how anyone would.

@AndyBonner Those are different, because those clauses qualify how you sweep or go. "becoming lifelong learners" is something else you do in addition to exploring the rorld.

I didn't notice the context of this being on a doorway, I think I'll revise my answer.

Well, as I mentioned in my comment on Greybeard's, I strongly suspect that "here" was meant to mean "this school." I suppose it's speculation though.

There may be some synecdoche there. But it's not uncommon to refer to thesholds as the place where a change takes place.


Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Yes, but it does not mean what the writer intended it to.
"Explore the world through here, becoming lifelong learners" is understood as
"Explore the world that is on the other side of this place, becoming lifelong learners.

Through, as a preposition, can indicate a means (the instrumental): "He succeeded through (by means of) working hard." Here, it is similar to "by". This use of "through"

We cannot say "Explore the world by here."
We can say "Explore the world by learning here."

Through can also mean "from one side (of something) to the other" - "The arrow went through his armour." / "The car went through the tunnel."


It's unfortunate it's posted over a doorway, inviting the "on the other side" meaning; I strongly suspect it's just an institutional slogan, cooked up without necessarily planning to put it on a doorway, and intended the "by means of" meaning. In which case "here" (meaning "this school," not "this doorway") is not a great idiomatic choice.
